# Categories and .orderedtest in MSTest (console)

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest, ordered-test

is there a way to use categories and ordered tests in MSTest together?

```
[TestMethod, TestCategory("UITest")]
public void TestMethod()
{
}
```

and add a new ordered test to my test project.

well .. calling this method from the command line like:

```
MSTest.exe /testcontainer:MyOrderedTest.orderedtest
```

it will execute the testmethod.

but when calling MSTest like the following:

```
MSTest.exe /testcontainer:MyOrderedTest.orderedtest /category:UITest
```

it can't find the testmethod..

strange behavior ..

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `/testcontainer:[file name]` option you tell MSTest to run the tests that are specified in this file. So, your unit test with the attribute `[TestMethod, TestCategory("UITest")]` will not run because it not contained inside the `MyOrderedTest.orderedtest`.

You could create a `TestList` to achieve this behavior which will contain all of your Tests that belong to the `UITest` category and also the `OrderedTest` and then run the following command:

```
MSTest.exe /testmetadata:$(ProjectDir)\TestProject.vsmdi /testlist:ListName
```

Comment: hmmm .. this is really a inconvenient and inflexible way .. I believe it will work.. there is an alternative where you just sort your order by defining your names of testmethods alphanumericaly .. a need for orderedtest doesn't exist anymore here ... i don't know which way is more elegant -_-'

Comment: If the order is always the same then defining test methods alphanumerically sounds good. But, I'd prefer the OrderedTest because you can define only the test methods you want (regardless their test category) and you don't need to change them if new test methods were added or existing ones were renamed.